# MySql - On Duplicate Key

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I have a table:

```
Saves
-----
UserId (int primary key)
Save (blob)
SaveBackup (blob)
```

This is populated with this:

```
Saves(22, 'xyz', '')
```

I submit the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Saves (UserId, Save, SaveBackup) "
                        . "VALUES (:UserId1, :Save1, '') ON DUPLICATE KEY "
                        . "UPDATE Saves SET SaveBackup=Save, Save=:Save2 "
                        . "WHERE UserId=:UserId2");
$stmt->execute(array(':Save1' => 'zzz',
                ':Save2' => 'zzz',
                ':UserId1' => 22,
                ':UserId2' => 22));
```

It does not work, error in your SQL code. It works fine without all the stuff preceeding (and including) the ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `WHERE` in `INSERT`. It makes no sense, since the purpose of `INSERT` is to add a new row, not modify an existing row. When you use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` it figures out which row you want to update based on it having a duplication of the key you're trying to insert, so you don't need to tell it explicitly.

You also don't need to use two placeholders for the new value. In the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause you can use `VALUES(Save)` to mean the value that would have been inserted into the `Save` column if it were adding a new row.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Saves (UserId, Save, SaveBackup) "
                        . "VALUES (:UserId, :Save, '') ON DUPLICATE KEY "
                        . "UPDATE SaveBackup=Save, Save = VALUES(Save) ");
$stmt->execute(array(':Save' => 'zzz',
                     ':UserId' => 22));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I marked it as answer, but then tried it and it still does not work. It says it fails around: 'Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET SaveBackup=Save, Save=VALUES(Save)' at line 1..

Comment: You had an extra `Saves` after `UPDATE` and I copied it into the answer.

Comment: Also there shouldn't be `SET` there. It's just `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = val1, col2 = val2, ...`